# Interactions between timezone info in python, numpy, matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib, timezone

I am plotting some data that is in a format like

```
06:55:00.0 0.6002
```

i.e., `hh:mm:ss.f` (or `"%H:%M:%S.%f"` in [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) format) followed by a float.

I have been reading these with the somewhat baroque incantation (simplifying suggestions welcome!)

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

def makedt(timestr):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, "%H:%M:%S.%f")

datetau = np.genfromtxt(fname, converters={0:makedt, 1:np.float}, 
              dtype={'names':('date', 'tau'), 'formats':('datetime64[s]', np.float)})
```

(In fact I do something slightly more complicated, using `datetime.datetime.combine()` in my `makedt` to get the correct date rather than the default 1 Jan 1900.)

I am currently in the "HST" timezone (more importantly, my computer is), and these data are in fact referenced to that timezone. My understanding is that data are assumed to come from the *local* timezone `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()`, which is set from the system value of the timezone.

To plot the data, I can do something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dateutil

mytz = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(datetau['date'].astype(datetime.datetime), datetau['tau'], tz=mytz)
```

Note that I *need* the `tz=mytz`, or otherwise the data get shifted to the wrong time/date i.e., to the default matplotlib value (usually UTC, or as otherwise set in `matplotlibrc`) -- and it would be even more complicated (or at least technically incorrect) if I weren't actually in HST. This isn't so bad. But in fact if I want to play with ticks and labels, I need to specify the timezone for each of them, as in:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%m-%d %H:%M" ,tz=hst))
```

It's not terribly onerous, but it seems brittle, since as I said above the default behaviour when reading is to assume the *local* timezone. What happens if you move the computer between reading the data and plotting it? (I don't know if the local TZ changes!)

What I'd really like to do is just tell python/numpy/matplotlib to never even worry about timezone information in this case. Is this possible?

(Also, as an aside, any cleanup of the `datetime` vs `datetime64` etc handling in the above would be appreciated.)

Comment: by any chance do you have a timezone specified in your `matplotlibrc` file? (`print(plt.rcParams['timezone'])`)

Comment: I don't have it explicitly set -- it defaults to UTC.

Comment: ok -- in that case, if your dates are stored in the correct timezone, then i would keep this whole process as timezone-agnostic as possible.

Comment: agreed -- but is that what I'm already doing, or is there a better (easier, more agnostic) way?